# Push docker image to another container registry with compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-image, locust

I am running locust (the official image from Docker Hub) locally using a Docker-compose file as below

```
version: '3'

services:
  locust:
    image: locustio/locust
    ports:
     - "8089:8089"
    volumes:
      - ./:/mnt/locust
    command: -f /mnt/locust/locustfile.py -H https://my-host-url.com
```

I have done the stress-testing in my local with `docker-compose up`. The next step is to push this compose file onto another registry. I am following the steps given in docker hub documentation. However, I just need some help in copying the necessary locustfile.py as well to my other registry (let's say artifactory).

Comment: What are you doing with the images after being pushed to your local registry?

Comment: I test it locally and if everything works fine, I want to deploy it into the prod environment

Comment: But then it would be enough to have the single container image in your local registry and deploy it to prod with exactly the same docker compose file. So your build pipeline should pull the image and push it to your local registry. The docker compose file is source controlled and used by your deployment process.

Answer (score 3):

To upload an image to your custom registry it has to be properly tagged (named) and it is not necessary to use `docker build` for that. You can do with `docker tag`:

```
# pull the image
docker pull locustio/locust

# rename it for your registry
docker tag locustio/locust:latest my-registry.com:5000/locust:latest

# push it to your registry using its new name
docker push my-registry.com:5000/locust:latest
```